# How to recover list of geofire locations in a listview or recyclerview android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-recyclerview, geofire

I want to recover a list of queried geofire locations in a listview or recycler view. In my example I would like to receive two locations within my radius which is construction and cleaning.

[Firebase goefire json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY8Wn.png)

My code is as follows

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("geofire/home");
    geoFire = new GeoFire(databaseReference);

//My current location
geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(-1.320252, 36.841984), 0.6);

geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            textView.setText("entered"+" "+key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            textView.setText("exited");
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Or are you uncertain [how to create a custom adapter to show the data in a list view](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+a+custom+adapter+to+show+the+data+in+a+list+view)?

Comment: One of my biggest problem is once i get the keys for the geofire query i cannot put them in a listview, custom adapter or recycler view. Thats the help i need

Comment: can someone please help, i would like to get every location in the radius and display them in a listview